# get DHCP address of connection to router

Tags: php, localhost, dhcp

I run MAMP to do local wordpress development and for various reasons I need to access the sites via something like `http://192.162.1.99:8888` rather than `http://localhost:8888`. This is generally not a problem whilst on my own connection as I always connect with the same IP. However when out and about I have to mess about and change various constants to reflect the IP I'm on with that router.

So is there a technique using PHP that can ascertain this DHCP address? Nothing within `$_SERVER` returns this address, `['SERVER_ADDR']` & `['REMOTE_ADDR']` contain `::1` and `['HTTP_HOST']` contains `localhost:8888`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely not the cleanest solution, but if you are running Linux/Unix you can run the below php system call in your script.  I have not tested it but I believe it will provide you with the correct IP in the variable.  Just remember to switch en1 with your actual ethernet/wireless adapter name for your system.  You may also need to use the exact path to the ifconfig command.

```
$ipAddress = system('ifconfig en1 | grep inet | cut -d" " -f2' , $returnVal);
```

Sorry if the variable names are not in the php standard, I normally develop in Java these days.

Comment: Yep, the number is in there. Not totally clean but enough to work with - many thanks.

Comment: Actually it does just return the IP to the variable, but the function itself actually outputs various other things (some variation of the MAC address plus the adaptor name). Use exec() instead of system() and this will only return the value, not output anything directly.

Comment: @artparks , Thanks for the note about using exec instead.  I only tried this on the command line, not actually through php.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the previous answer by Lipongo;
if the devicename is known this will work on systems without ifconfig:

```php
$dev = 'eth1';
$ip4 = exec('ip addr show '.$dev.' | grep -oP "(?<=inet ).+(?=/)"');
$ip6 = exec('ip addr show '.$dev.' | grep -oP "(?<=inet6 ).+(?=/)"');
```